# get a string value from its name

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string name given to me in a string.

### Like this:

```
string myawesomestring = "hey";
string mystringname = "myawesomestring";
```

I need to get `myawesomestring` value but the `myawesomestring` can change.

I hope you get what I mean, if you don't comment I will fix it myself.

Comment: I know it was something like ["string name"] but I do not know exact

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbody.localvariables?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) ?

Comment: the short version: you do **not** want to do that unless you know **precisely** what you are doing, and why.

Comment: string thekey = RandomString(64);
            string thekey2 = RandomString(64);
            string thekey3 = RandomString(64);
            string thekey4 = RandomString(64);

i need to add them togheter but in a random order

Comment: IF they are all random, the same order every time is still random - so `string randomstring = RandomString(64 * 4)` should suffice.

Comment: This is really starting to sound like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: trying to make as random as possible

Comment: Then declare 256 random chars and assemble them in a random order. which by the way is just like creating a random string with 256 characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
string mystringname += myawesomestring;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to read the value of a string by some kind of string value stored in another variable (which is dynamic). I don't think this can be achieved with just simple string data type, but you can do this by using some complex data types like dictionary or class or something similar.

First solution might be storing the data in a dictionary, but you have to make sure the keys are unique. E.g.

```
string mystringname1 = "MyAwesomeString1";
string mystringname2 = "MyAwesomeString2";

var awesomeStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"MyAwesomeString1","hey1" },
    {"MyAwesomeString2","hey2" }
};

string vaule1 = awesomeStrings[mystringname1];
string vaule2 = awesomeStrings[mystringname2];
```

If you have more attributes, then you can create a class and with the use of little bit of reflection, you can easily read the property values. E.g.

```
public class AwesomeString
{
    public string MyAwesomeString1 { get; set; } = "hey1";
    public string MyAwesomeString2 { get; set; } = "hey2";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mystringname1 = "MyAwesomeString1";
        string mystringname2 = "MyAwesomeString2";

        AwesomeString awesomeString = new AwesomeString();

        string vaule1 = (string)awesomeString.GetType().GetProperty(mystringname1).GetValue(awesomeString);
        string vaule2 = (string)awesomeString.GetType().GetProperty(mystringname2).GetValue(awesomeString);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```